# How do you register a Key Chord for a Vscode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There are various standard key-cords in VsCode such as `ctrl + e` or `ctrl + k` sometimes. Their operations are a bit different to key binding, after pressing one of the starting key binds to initiate the sequence, you can press another key like `a`, `b` or any other hot keys to conclude the sequence. My question is, how do we register a starting key-bind (`ctrl + e`-like) or a key sequence (`ctrl + e`, `a`) using the VsCode API?

Comment: separate them with a space in the keybinding definition

Comment: Hey, @rioV8 thank you for the answer. If you wouldn't mind, is there a way I could register a keybind through code rather than the `package.json` that it provided? I need to do it through code.

Comment: why do you need to do it with code? if it is based on user input then let the user define the key biding, you can't handle it for all users because some of them have keyboards (language) that use certain key combos for special characters or that can't define certain key combos

Comment: That's true, I probably shouldn't have the need to do it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @rioV8, all we need to do is to separate the key chord with spaces.

```json
      },
      {
        "command": "SOME_COMMAND",
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+b",
      },
      {
        "command": "SOME_COMMAND",
        "key": "ctrl+' a",
      },
```